# How to find elements in a QString to the right of a character

Tags: c++, qt

I have a filename as a QString which looks like "c:/ ..... /whatIAmActuallyInterestedIn.stuff"

I want to get all the information after the last /, which in this case would be whatIAmActuallyInterestedIn.stuff

Right now, I know that I can convert this to a std::string, use rfind to find the last / in the string, and then convert it back to a QString for then outputting.  However, this seems like doing an excessive amount of work for something that I am fairly certain QString has built in, I just can't find the function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the file name like this:

```
QFileInfo("c:/ ..... /whatIAmActuallyInterestedIn.stuff").fileName();
```

Comment: This answers the specific problem of the OP, but not the general question.

Answer (score 1):

```
QString shortName = longName.right(longName.findRev("/") + 1);
```

But the `QFileInfo` answer by svlasov is better if that's what you're really looking for.

Comment: Is `longName` a QString too? I don't see the `findRev()` method in it.